# Implementing mathematical concepts on a webpage

Tags: java, html, math, web, statistics

I have been given the task to create an online (client-side) implementation of a statistical method. The method is relatively easily programmed in R/SPLUS for example, but I understand to do this within a webpage and client side I will end up having to program some statistical concepts myself which is fine. However I am looking for advice on what the most practical language is for dealing with the following task within a webpage:

1. Accepting input from a user
2. Taking this input, and performing various reasonably high level mathematical calculations (such as matrix algebra)
3. Returning the output to the user

With my very limited knowledge, a Java applet seems the most obvious option. However, my question is, are there any other ways of achieving this goal without an applet (i.e. would javascript suffice) and what would be your advice on the most robust/user-friendly/appropriate language to do this? The main aim is accessibility to the widest possible audience.

Comment: You mess up an interface and a library implementation. Firs you have to understand CS concepts.

Comment: Look for a third party javascript library that handles the types of math you'd like to do.  One most likely already exists. All you'd have to do is learn the syntax for that javascript library.

Comment: Roman C - I am not a computer scientist so I am unlikely to write like one. Can you be a bit more elaborate specific your point? thanks

Comment: aglassman - Most of what I'll need to do is likely matrix or vector manipulation hopefully, I see there are libraries that deal with this. Do you think javascript is better from an end-user perspective to (say) a java applet?

Comment: @ShaunKillingbeck Very. Most major operating systems don't ship with the JRE - or, in the case of OS X, with Java plugins enabled - out of the box. Asking users to install a JRE or fiddle with System Preferences is an uncomfortable hurdle

Comment: @ShaunKillingbeck I'd say I'm reasonably good at using computers, and when I find a site that requires Java applets to show an animation, I tend to groan and look for an alternative resource instead. Even Flash tends to load quicker and look better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend first looking into JavaScript as it is supported on all major browsers and doesn't require additional plugins to be installed, so it seems to be the ideal candidate for your "widest possible audience" requirement.

As for supporting high level mathematical calculations, you will likely want to find a good library to use.  I do not know all your needs, but a simple search for *JavaScript "Matrix Algebra" Library* came up with [this](http://sylvester.jcoglan.com/api/matrix.html) as the first result, which looks promising.

If you do not find a library that meets all your needs, you could build the mathematical functions you'll need yourself.  That may sound foreboding, but keep in mind that all high-level functions are built off of lower-level functions, and since JavaScript is a functional language, it is well-suited for building that type of functionality.  However, I don't know your programming knowledge, your commitment-level to the project, or the complexity of the functions you will need.  Thus, if that proves too cumbersome a task and Java handles everything you need well, then an applet is a good second option.

Comment: Thank you! This confirms what I had guessed. I was thinking JavaScript would be good for being accessible to a wider audience but I was just unsure if it would have enough functionality - but I believe the library you mentioned does most things I will need, although it might be necessary for me to find eigenvalues/vectors of a matrix which it doesn't seem to cope with. Hopefully there will be another package that can handle that.

Answer (score 0):

a java applet is probably the *easiest* way to do this. javascript will get you a wider audience.